# SSRS column background color formatting not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have the following requirement:
A column has negative values and NA values as well. The negative and NA value cells should be "Red" and other cells should be "light grey". I have written the following expression for this:

```
=IIF(Fields!BaseDOS.Value ="NA" OR Fields!BaseDOS.Value < 0, "Red", "LightGrey")
```

But it is not working for NA fields. Also I am using expression to show the negative values in parentheses:

=Format(Fields!BaseDOS.Value,"##0.00;(##0.00)")

This is also not working. Please help.

Comment: Check the values for Fields!BaseDOS in the query output (Just to make sure you are getting "NA", negative values also)

Answer (score 2):

You should really post each problem as a separate question.

In the background color property for the text box try:

```
=IIF(Fields!BaseDOS.Value ="NA" OR Fields!BaseDOS.Value < "0", "Red", "LightGrey")
```

BaseDos must be a string.

In the format property for the textbox you want to show parenthesis try:

```
#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)
```

Comment: But BaseDOS is integer here, is there a way to make it work with integar?

Comment: It **cannot** be an integer field if you are also storing "NA".